# R max function gives NA

Tags: r, function, max, na

I have the following data:

`x=as.data.frame(c(NA,NA,5,20,25,50,75,8,NA))`

Why does `max(x)` produce "NA" as result? NA cannot be the maximum. What is the logic behind this behavior?

In the end, only `max(x, na.rm = TRUE)` gives the correct maximum, but I wonder why.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is the maximum of 5 and an unknown quantity? It's an unknown quantity... could be 5 but we can't be sure.

Comment: it is mentioned in docs `By definition the min/max of a numeric vector containing an NaN is NaN, except that the min/max of any vector containing an NA is NA even if it also contains an NaN. Note that max(NA, Inf) == NA even though the maximum would be Inf whatever the missing value actually is.` and `If na.rm is FALSE an NA value in any of the arguments will cause a value of NA to be returned, otherwise NA values are ignored.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The logic behind missing values management in R language is that returning missing values (NA in R) for computations such as `max`, `min`, `mean`, `sd`, etc. *allows the missing values to be taken into account* in the computation: these NA values could not be used in the computation otherwise (see point 2 of my answer). Similarly,`nchar` will returns NA when computed with a "NA" string, since NA is different of an empty character string (""). In addition, this behavior allows the analyst to understand that the computation involves missing values, if he has not checked that or forget the `na.rm = T` argument.
2. Other languages do not consider missing values in this kind of operations. For example in SQL you would get the effective highest number with max() and the lowest with min() - in your example the result would be 75 and 5 respectively, but missing values (NULL in SQL) will never be included in these results: *in SQL, a NULL value will never be identified as the minimum or maximum*. One could say that missing values are 'nowhere' in this SQL-case; unlike the handling of missing values in R, where they are the result.